# Python - euclidean distance of all pairs of subsequences of given length from given array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have an numpy array [5,7,2,3,4,6] and I choose length of subsequence to be 3.

I want to get euclidean distances of such subsequences.

Possible subsequences are:

1. [5,7,2]
2. [7,2,3]
3. [2,3,4]
4. [3,4,6]

Distance between subsequence 1. and 3. would be calculated as (5-2)^2 + (7-3)^2 + (2-4)^2. I want to do this for all pairs of subsequences.

Is there a way to avoid loops?

My real array is quite long so the solution should be memory efficient as well.

EDIT>

To elaborate more: I have a timeseries of size 10^5 to 10^8 elements

Time series is growing. each time new point is added I need to take the L newest points and find a closest match to these points in the past points of the dataset. (But I want all value of distances not only to find the closest match)

Repeating the whole calculation is unnecessary. The distance of "previously newest L points" can be updated and only modified by substracting point of age L+1 and adding point of age 0 (the newest).

E.g. lets say size of time series is currently 100 and L=10. I calculate distances of subsequence A[90:100] to all previous subsequences. When 101st point arrives I can reuse the distances and only update them by adding a squares of distances of 101st point from the time series and substracting squares of 90th point.

EDIT 2>

Thanks a lot for the ideas, looks like magic. I have one more idea that might be efficient especially for the online time series when new elements of tiem series are being added.

I am thinking about this way of updating the distances. To calculate distances of first subsequence of length L=4 to the matrix we need to have first 4 columns of the following matrix (the triangles on top and bottom could be ommited). Then the distances would be squared and summed as shown with colors.

[image]

To obtain the distances of second subsequence of L=4 we can actually reuse the previously calculated distances and substract first column (squared) from them and add 4th column(squared). For L=4 it might not make sense but for L=100 it might. One distance has to be calculated from scratch. (Actually 2 have to be calculated if the Time series grows in size).

[image]

This way I can keep in memory just the distances of one subsequence and update them to obtain distances of next subsequence.

Do you think this would be efficient with numpy? Is there an easy way to implement it?

Comment: do you want all possible combinations of subsequence pairs, or a function that given two subsequence indexes will return the distance?

Comment: I think your formula needs to be wrapped in a `sqrt()`: sqrt((5-2)^2 + (7-3)^2 + (2-4)^2).

Comment: With 10^8 elements, we are looking at 0.5x10^16 elements as the output. I don't know the math, but that would need a huge storage in memory space. Even if we forget about the computation involved for a moment, are you sure the output from it could be stored?

Comment: @Divakar It would be enough if distanced of one subsequence vs rest of time series is stored in memory at the time, then can be updated to obtain next one. Added some pictures.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `A` as the input array and `L` as the length of subsequence, you can get a sliding 2D array version of `A` with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and then use [`pdist` from scipy.spatial.distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist), like so -

```
# Get sliding 2D array version of input array
A2D = A[np.arange(A.size-L+1)[:,None] + np.arange(L)]

# Get pairwise distances with pdist
pairwise_dist = pdist(A2D,'sqeuclidean')
```

Please note that if you meant euclidean distances, you need to replace `'sqeuclidean'` with `'euclidean'` or just leave out that argument as it's the default one.

Sample run -

```
In [209]: # Inputs
     ...: A = np.array([5,7,2,3,4,6])
     ...: L = 3
     ...: 

In [210]: A2D = A[np.arange(A.size-L+1)[:,None] + np.arange(L)]

In [211]: A2D
Out[211]: 
array([[5, 7, 2],
       [7, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 6]])

In [212]: pdist(A2D,'sqeuclidean')
Out[212]: array([ 30.,  29.,  29.,  27.,  29.,   6.])
          # [1] element (= 29) is (5-2)^2 + (7-3)^2 + (2-4)^2
```

To get the correspinding IDs, you could use [`np.triu_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) like so -

```
idx1,idx2 = np.triu_indices(A2D.shape[0],1)
```

And, finally show IDs alongside the distances like so -

```
ID_dist = np.column_stack((idx1,idx2,pairwise_dist))
```

Sample run -

```
In [201]: idx1,idx2
Out[201]: (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3]))

In [202]: np.column_stack((idx1,idx2,pairwise_dist))
Out[202]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,  30.],
       [  0.,   2.,  29.], # This was your (5-2)^2 + (7-3)^2 + (2-4)^2
       [  0.,   3.,  29.],
       [  1.,   2.,  27.],
       [  1.,   3.,  29.],
       [  2.,   3.,   6.]])
```

---

For cases, when you are dealing millions of elements in `A` and `L` is in hundreds, it might be a better idea to perform computations for each pairwise differentiations of such sub-sequences in a loop, like so -

```
# Get pairiwise IDs
idx1,idx2 = np.triu_indices(A.size-L+1,1)

# Store range array for L as would be used frequently in loop
R = np.arange(L)

# Initialize output array and start computing
pairwise_dist = np.empty(len(idx1))
for i in range(len(idx1)):
    pairwise_dist[i] = ((A[R+idx2[i]] - A[R+idx1[i]])**2).sum()
```

You can also use `np.einsum` to get us the squared summations at each iteration, like so -

```
diffs = A[R+idx2[i]] - A[R+idx1[i]]
pairwise_dist[i] = np.einsum('i,i->',diffs,diffs)
```

Comment: OP asked for Euclidean distance, you're providing squared Euclidean (`sqeuclidean`). Otherwise, looks like a good answer :)

Comment: @EelkeSpaak Well OP listed `(5-2)^2 + (7-3)^2 + (2-4)^2` as one of the sample values. So, I deduced that would be sq-euclidean distances.

Comment: @EelkeSpaak Added that as a comment in the post :)

Comment: @Divakar thanks for interesting ideas. I see the problem with the creation of the indexing array `np.arange(A.size-L+1)[:,None] + np.arange(L)`  if this has to be allocated to memory at once it will have size len(A)*L. len(A) can be in milions, L can be in hundreds.

Comment: @nothinkelse Added a complimentary loopy version.